# Запись данных в свойство класса

Tags: c++

```
class BigInt
{
  private:
    static const int max_length = 300;
    int c;
    int number[max_length];

    int to_int(char symbol)
    {
        return (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9') ? (int)symbol - '0' : -1;
    }
  public:
    BigInt(char* str)
    {
        c = strlen(str) - 1;
        int pos = 0;

        if (c > max_length)
        {
            cout << "Max length is " << max_length << "but your number has length"
                 << c << endl;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = c; i <= 0; i--)
        {
            number[pos] = to_int(str[i]);
            pos++;
        }
    }
    void printNumber(void)
    {
        for (int i = c; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout << number[i];
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }
};
```

Есть конструктор, который принимает строку-число, цифры которого записывает в массив number. 
При выводе данного массива получаю почему-то рандомные значения.

```
int main(void)
    {
        char str[]="111111111";
        BigInt test(str);
        test.printNumber();

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = c;i<=0;i--)
```

Ну, т.е. пока `i` не больше нуля, то...

Условие вы поставили неверное.

Я бы вообще переписал ваш код так:

```
class BigInt
{
private:
    static const int max_length = 300;
    int number[max_length];
    unsigned int c;

    static int to_int(char symbol)
    {
        if (symbol < '0' || symbol > '9') throw exception("Wrong input");
        return symbol - '0';
    }

public:
    BigInt(const char * str)
    {
        c = strlen(str);
        if (c > max_length) throw exception("Wrong length");
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        {
            number[i] = to_int(str[c-i-1]);
        }
    }
    void printNumber(void)
    {
        for(int i = c-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout<<number[i];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
};
```

И еще - имя `c` для переменной, которая должна что-то означать в классе - не годится. Это имя для локальной переменной цикла, например... но не для длины числа.

Answer (score 3):

```
c = strlen(str) - 1;
```

Зачем вы вычитаете 1? Длина она и есть длина, не надо.

```
for(int i = c;i>=0;i--)
```

`<=` допустим, что опечатка.
Да, не опечатка, а ошибка...  =)

Как-то так:

```
BigInt(char * str){
    c = strlen(str);
    int pos=0;
    if(c > max_length){
        cout<<"Max length is "<<max_length<<"but your number has length"<<c<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        number[pos] = to_int(str[i]);
        pos++;
    }
}
void printNumber(void){
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        cout<<number[i]<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```